# Struts2- How to reduce the execution time

Tags: struts2, interceptor, interceptorstack

I've developed a portal using Struts2, where most of the actions are called through Ajax calls. But, I'm seeing some unexpected execution time for each action to get executed. For example, for an action where there is no DB calls or any other, where only a search box is returned, it takes about 250~300 mS.

So far I've tried the below steps, but not much improvements in the execution timings. Please advice what could be done in order to make it faster.

- Removed Dev mode in Struts
- Stopped using defaultStack & tried using basicStack as the interceptor stack
- Enabled templatesCache
- Set templatesCache.updateDelay as 60000

**Edit:**

I'm seeing this error even though there are no issues in the functionality. Any idea whether this has any relationship with the delay please?

```
ERROR finder.ClassFinder: Unable to read class [WEB-INF.classes.com.***.***.ConfigManagement]
Could not load WEB-INF/classes/com/***/***/ConfigManagement.class - [unknown location]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.finder.ClassFinder.readClassDef(ClassFinder.java:785)
```

Comment: Please don't create a new question if it's been edited into an existing question.

Comment: I was not sure whether this edit will get notified. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

> [Struts2 Performance Tuning](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.4/docs/performance-tuning.html)

1. Do not use interceptors you do not need. Identify and remove that from basicStack.
2. [TimerInterceptor](https://struts.apache.org/2.0.6/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/interceptor/TimerInterceptor.html) to identify action execution time try reduce it.
3. For Struts 2 versions before 2.3: the OGNL version 3.0.3 library is a drop-in replacement for older OGNL jars, and provides much better performance.

Comment: Well, I've been using the TimerInterceptor to check the timings, will be removing it after fixing the performance issue. I'm already using the OGNL 3.0.3 version. Any practical experience about the time taken for each action? Is this 250~300 mS is acceptable value for a simple action execution?